# Como instanciar um GridView ou um ListView para mesma Activity?

Tags: java, android, listview, gridview

Em meu app estou apresentando uma lista de itens. Gostaria que em determinadas situações fosse apresentado com um `ListView` e em outras como `GridView`. As situações são:

1. Smartphone(portrait) - `ListView`
2. Smartphone(landscape) e Tablet - `GridView`

### Pergunta

Como eu poderia checar cada situação e instanciar corretamente o objeto na `Activity`?

**OBS**: A parte de xml já está feita, com as pastas da maneira correta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recebi a resposta em um outro fórum onde perguntei também e recebi como resposta uma ótima solução, copiarei aqui pois pode ajudar mais alguém futuramente. Apliquei em meu aplicativo e funcionou.

> Suponha que o XML contendo a `ListView` ou o `GridView` se chame `layout.xml`. Então:
>
> - na pasta `layout`, deve haver um `layout.xml` com `ListView`.
> - na pasta `layout-land` e layout-large deve haver um `layout.xml` com `GridView`.
>
> Com isso feito, o Android já vai inflar o `layout.xml` correto ao fazer:
>
> ```
> setContentView(R.layout.layout);
> ```
>
> Como tanto ListView quanto GridView são filhos de AbsListView, faça o seguinte:
>
> ```
> AbsListView listOrGrid = 
>     (AbsListView) findViewById(R.id.id_do_grid_e_list);
> ```

Enviada por Lucas no GUJ(Espero que não haja problemas em citar outro fórum)

Answer (score 5):

Você deve trabalhar com tamanhos de tela. A maneira mais comum que eu aprendi foi o de utilizar um resource com uma propriedade boolean is (você pode colocar o nome que quiser, isGrid, por exemplo), geralmente utilizam isTablet.

Primeiro, você deve criar uma pasta values para cada qualificador que você tem de layout. Por exemplo, caso você tenha layout-land, layout-large-land, layout-xlarge então você deve também deve ter as pastas values-land, values-large-land e values-xlarge.

Depois você deve criar dentro de cada umas das pastas values um arquivo bool.xml com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="isGrid">false</bool>
</resources>
```

O valor true ou false muda de acordo com a existência do gridView, caso exista um gridView você deve colocar true, caso contrário false.

Agora na activity que chama o gridView ou o ListView você adiciona o seguinte código:

```
private boolean isGrid(){
    return getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isGrid);
}
```

Agora no método onCreate da mesma activity você deve ter um código com o seguinte:

```
if(this.isGrid()){
    //crie uma gridView
}
else{
    //crie uma listView
}
```

Comment: Vlw por ajudar, eu recebi uma resposta que funcionou muito bem. Publiquei ela aqui para que possa ajudar a outros.

Answer (score 4):

Se for necessário checar a orientação, você pode usar:

```java
getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
```

que pode ser uma das seguintes constantes:

```java
ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE 
ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
```

e para checar se a tela é grande(Tablet) você pode tentar pegar as polegadas(diagonais) do dispositivo:

```java
public static Double getPolegadas(Activity activity) {

    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

    final int largura = metrics.widthPixels;
    final int altura = metrics.heightPixels;
    final double diagonal = Math.sqrt((largura * largura) + (altura * altura));

    polegadas = diagonal / metrics.densityDpi;

    return polegadas;
}
```

Aí para Tablet, você checaria se é maior que 6.5, por exemplo:

```java
if (polegadas >= 6.5)
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, recebi uma resposta mais simples e que funcionou muito bem, publiquei ela aqui para que possa ajudar a outros.

Comment: @ribeirojpn Não se esqueça de aceitar a melhor resposta. Abraço!